# how do i make sure the value in a table entity is not repeated in mysql?

Tags: mysql

in the below table i would want the property_id to be unique so that it doesn't have duplicate values. what is the syntax for this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `propFeatures` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`bedroom` int(10) NOT NULL,
`bathroom` int(10) NOT NULL,
`balcony` int(10) NOT NULL,
`furnished` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`property_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `UNIQUE` constraint to your `property_id` column so that it does not allow duplicates if you want.

---

To check duplicates, you can run this query:

```
select property_id, count(property_id) as total from propFeatures
       group by property_id having count(property_id) > 1
```

If you want to remove duplicates, check out this post for more info:

[MySQL: Remove Duplicate Rows/Records from Table](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2008/06/mysql-remove-duplicate-rows-records.html)